# how to display interval data in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

Sorry for bad title but I didn't know how to phrase it.

I have data shaped like this:

```js
type Data = {
   start_date: Date,
   end_date: Date,
   num_of_intervals: number,
   sums: number[]
}
```

Basically lets say if

```js
const data = {
   start_date: '2023-10-03',
   end_date: '2023-10-04',
   num_of_intervals: 2,
   sums: [10, 20]

}
```

this means that for the first part of the day the sum is 10 and the second part of the day the sum is 20.

I basically want to have a chart that spans from start_date to end_date but have ticks at the middle of them. So for the sample data, the ticks would be at '2023-10-23 06:00' and '2023-10-23 18:00'

[image: desired output]

Is there a generic way of accomplishing this sort of thing?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a generic way to do exactly that kind of plot. `chart.js` draws lines, bars, axes, ticks, labels, etc. but you have to tell it in its own (simple and well documented) format where and how you want those drawn. If the question is only about making the x axis extend outside of the data interval, you can achieve that in multiple ways, for instance creating labels with missing or `null` values.